# Advice on datamodel structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-design

I'm practicing with ASP.Net MVC 5, and I'm attempting to build a prototype events directory. I've started with a basic layout, adapted from the Contoso University tutorial, but I want to start to develop a more complex data model, however I'm unsure as to the best way to develop the model, specifically, the different pricing options each listing can have.

My current data model is;

**Vendors**

```
 public class Vendor
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Company Name")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Company name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
    public string ContactFirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Last name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
    public string ContactLastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Address Line 2")]
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Region { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Twitter @username")]
    public string TwitterHandle { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Facebook URL")]
    public string FacebookURL { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Active Vendor?")]
    public Boolean ActiveStatus { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Listing> Listings { get; set; }
}
```

**Listings**

```
public class Listing
{
    public int ListingID { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public int VendorID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Listing Name")]
    public string ListingName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Listing Description")]
    public string ListingDesc { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Maximum Capacity")]
    public int Capacity { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Display(Name = "Price Per Guest")]
    public decimal PricePerGuest { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Address Line 2")]
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Postcode { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Vendor Vendor { get; set; }
}
```

**Categories**

```
 public class Category
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public string CategoryDescription { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Listing> Listings { get; set; }
    }
```

Ideally, I'd like to add to the Listing table a new property called 'Fixed Price', giving vendors the option to either list by price per guest or by fixed price, as not all vendors can price their services by price per guest.

Is a separate table with pricing options sufficient enough to develop this further?

P.S - I haven't yet started to format the entities properly yet, hence why categories is missing validation and so on.

Comment: `Price` (currency) and `IsFixedPrice` (bit) Instead of `PricePerGuest`

Comment: Hi @Nikhil, thanks for the response. This makes sense, however, if the response to 'IsFixedPrice' - would there be some conditional logic required or an alternative entity to provide price per guest, or would it just be assumed that the price entered, if not fixed, is the price per guest?

Comment: "would it just be assumed that the price entered, if not fixed, is the price per guest?" - Yes

Answer (score 0):

`Price` (currency) and `IsFixedPrice` (bit) Instead of `PricePerGuest`

Thanks to @Nikhil Vartak for the answer